# How can I control where Wordpress injects code from a plugin (into the page)

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress plugin that appears abandoned by its author.

The plugin makes 1 terrible mistake that I'm trying to fix: It injects itself in the top of the page, on top of everything else, at the beginning of the head element. That causes problems and is bad practice.

How can I edit this beast so it will inject itself just before /head?

Is there a function like this:

`injectAtHeadClose(<?php echo "stuff that don't belong in the first line of the page.");?>`

Or maybe some other way to achieve this? I'm sure that most plugins control where their code gets injected, but I just don't know how.

Sorry if I'm misusing the word "inject."

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for hooks. There are two types in wordpress - filters and actions.

Here is an explanation of the plugin API (Hooks):

[Plugin API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)

[List of Actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

[List of Filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)